# val() of jquery does not take value of all input

Tags: jquery

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
<input type="text" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" placeholder="Birth Date (DD/MM/YYYY)" />
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
<input type="password" id="repassword" name="repassword" placeholder="Re-Password" />
<button type="button" id="button">Submit</button>

<p id="test"></p>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").on("click", function(){            
        var fn=$('#fname').val(),
            ln=$('#lname').val(),
            bd=$('#birthdate').val(),
            email=$('#email').val(),
            pw=$('#password').val(),
            rpw=$('#repassword').val();
        $('#test').text(fn+ln+bd+email+pw+rpw);
    });
});
```

I get values for `fn`, `ln`, `bd` and `rpw`, but not `email` and `pw`. What is the wrong with `email` and `pw`?

Comment: post your HTML please so we can test or a Fiddle.

Comment: Try running `console.log($('[id=email]').length);` .  If it returns a number greater than one, you have duplicate ids.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say without looking at the rest of the page's source code, but I'd wager there are existing elements in your webpage with IDs `#email` and `#password` and that jQuery is selecting those, and then getting an `undefined` or blank value from them.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Console says there are two of each element. But in my code they are hidden. I think I should rewrite the page.